# Project Server Application Service missing from Services List

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2013, service-application

I've installed Sharepoint and Project Server 2013. I do not see **Project Server Application Service** on the Service list. How do I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-run the configuration wizard and it solved the problem. Weird but it works!